# Awarding experience from discoveries on an uncharted land

Tags: cypher-system

I'm GMing a game were the setting is the fallout universe, all my players are vault dwellers and started the campaign underground, knowing nothing about the surface world. That mean that they're learning new things, on nearly every step.

On our first session, they've discovered mutants insects, ghouls, drugs hubs, and a ghoul city. They've learned a bit from everything mentioned above, everything looks like a discovery, but I'm wondering, Did they really just earned 8 exp just for discovering things on 4 hours of gameplay? or, I'm just been to generous with their earned xp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That said, this was a world shattering experience for them: *nothing* outside the vault was familiar. It was all weird, strange, and frightening.  From their points of view, the world has changed. It is not longer the same. Hell, there's *no ceiling*! How scary is that?...

So, you've been generous: It is not a problem. Remember, most XPs in Cipher are spend to re-roll dices, avoid Intrusions, and so on. Don't sweat it. XPs are tiny power up compared to ciphers.

That said, not every discovery merits XP and you could have said that "discover the world outside" is a discovery so they gain 1/2/3 XP from that. What they discovered is pretty common place in the wastelands.